# How to get triples from an Image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, ocr, triples

I have an image of a Block Diagram and I want to extract all the triples from that image like HEAD RELATION OBJECT based on that block diagram image. How I will get that?

Like from the given block diagram I want to extract triples like JOHN LIKES MANGO and ALLEN DISLIKES MANGO

[Block Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKJuA.jpg)

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I went through this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66363492/how-to-detect-whether-two-boxes-are-connected-with-each-other-or-not/67582494#67582494
But this one is only extracting Head and Tail, not the Relation which is in between the two boxes.

Comment: you might use [Template Matching](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) to detect the `like`, `dislike` relations.

Comment: But how I will get the "Like" with respect to "John" and "Mango" and "Dislike" with respect to "Allen" and "Mango" by template matching. If possible could you provide some code in python so that I can refer it as I am a beginner in this?